# Perl: Undo unlink with file open

Tags: perl, file, unlink

`unlink` does not delete a file, if it is open; it just removes the name and the link to the name. Can `unlink` be undone?

```
open(my $fh, ">", undef) || die;
print $fh "foo";
# This does not work
link($fh,"/tmp/bar") || die;
```

Can an open file handle to an unlinked file be linked to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers say: 'No, not in general, and definitely not on all Unices':

[Relinking an anonymous (unlinked but open) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171713/relinking-an-anonymous-unlinked-but-open-file)

https://serverfault.com/questions/168909/relinking-a-deleted-file

Copying the content from the open filehandle may work.

Comment: I completely agree, there is no facility for this and no procedure that works _in general_.  I am curious whether I am missing something, why do you say "_Copying the content from the open filehandle **may** work._" (emphasis mine)?  What I posted just works (or -- how can it not?), as long as the file is opened `rw`. (It doesn't restore the original link, of course.)

Comment: Copying content does not work if the whole reason for the relinking is to avoid re-reading the file (which it is in my case).

Comment: Ah, OK.  I didn't realize that that was the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If feasible, you can change the open mode (`'>'`) to be read/write instead. Then, when you need to recover the file you can use the filehandle to print it out to a newly opened file, even with the same name if needed.

```
open my $fh, '+>', $file;
say $fh "line 1";
unlink $file;
say $fh "more lines";

seek $fh, 0, 0;
open my $fh_rec, '>', $file   or die "Can't open $file (again): $!";
print $fh_rec $_ while <$fh>;
```

This isn't exactly what is asked but it recovers the file content and access
to it.  Further prints to `$fh` would leave the new `$file` out of sync, so this can be done when writing's done (to restore the file) or to switch the printing to `$fh_rec` (then also `close $fh`).

---

Another way to recover a file is by using the OS, if it uses `/proc` and exposes file handles. Then the data can be copied from `/proc/PID/fd/N`. To identify `N` one can scan all links that are in `fd/` (a few) with `ls -l`, since the deleted file should have `(deleted)` after its name.

Also, `lsof -p PID` lists all open file descriptors for the given process. The ones for deleted files have `(deleted)` with them.  (The `lsof +L1 -p PID` outputs only deleted entries, still quite a few.) From this output we can read off that file descriptor and then copy the data from `/proc/PID/fd/N`. This way we also get the inode number, which can also be used to recover the file.