# Naming an anonymous file pointer

Tags: c, posix, ansi-c

Given a file pointer *fp* which points to an open file, is there a portable way to give it a name? The function *rename* cannot be used in this case since I don't have a current name referring to the file.

Comment: "_points to an open file_"...what does that mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relinking an anonymous (unlinked but open) file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171713/relinking-an-anonymous-unlinked-but-open-file)

Comment: I think the "possible dupe" mostly answers your question -- you can't. The only possible difference is that your file might be linked to a filename somewhere, but it's still a security "thing" that you're not allowed to discover that relationship backwards.

Comment: @machine_1 I mean a FILE pointer which is not NULL (and not undefined).

Comment: Correction - the "possible dupe" does refer to `linkat` and `AT_EMPTY_PATH` which works on Linux since 2.6.39 (but probably isn't portable).

Answer (score 3):

On linux, you can use `linkat`

```
int linkat(int olddirfd, const char *oldpath,
           int newdirfd, const char *newpath, int flags);
```

by specifying the `AT_EMPTY_PATH` flag. For example, something like that:

```
linkat(fileno(fp), NULL, AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/new/name", AT_EMPTY_PATH);
```

Note that this does not rename the original file, it merely creates a new hard link to it (i.e. a new name). Also this approach is not portable, as the `AT_EMPTY_PATH` is a linux extension.

Comment: `fp` should be `fileno(fp)`, since he mentioned that `fp` is a `FILE*`.

Comment: This answer is confusing because the example call to `linkat` you wrote doesn't use the described `AT_EMPTY_PATH`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Oops, my bad, I fixed it.

Comment: `linkat` is not just Linux.  It's also [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html).  The [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) also has an interesting solution:  "If procfs is mounted, this can be used as an alternative to AT_EMPTY_PATH, like this: `linkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd/<fd>", newdirfd, newname, AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW);`"  That may work on non-Linux Unix systems with a `/proc` filesystem, also.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `linkat` is POSIX, but `AT_EMPTY_PATH` is linux specific.

Comment: @redneb True, but you'd already mentioned that.  I was just adding that `linkat` is POSIX and the relink method mentioned in the Linux man page may work on other Unix systems.